# HTTP Respond; Total size of payload

Tags: http, tcp, http-headers, ip, scapy

Is there a way to determine the total size of the payload if the Content-Length field is not available? I have access to IP, TCP, and UDP layer via scapy. Maybe I can determine the total size with one of those protocol?

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing strictly with HTTP, then it either needs to specify a **Content-Length** header, or specify via header that it's using a **Transfer-Encoding** which is well-defined (ie: chunked.).

If an HTTP response specifies chunked encoding, then you can't know how long it is until the end - it specifies that it will keep sending chunks until you receive a terminator (CRLF).

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't content-length field then the HTTP payload should carry the actual length of data of interest in the payload. Though you can have access to IP and TCP protocols, you will be able to fetch details of one particular packet and not of the HTTP payload for HTTP data can be received in multiple TCP packets.